# Visualizing 3d models with textures

Tags: python, 3d, textures, vtk, trimesh

I have a textured 3d model which has an obj file , mtl file and a png image for textures .
I can visualize them without textures using trimesh and vtkplotter as :

```
//trimesh//
m = trimesh.load("3dmodel.obj")

//vtkplotter//
m = load("3dmodel.obj")
```

But  they display the 3d models as plain meshes . 
I want to see them along with textures .

Can anyone please help me **View the 3d models along with textures** . 
Any small help would  be greatly helpful .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following:

```py
from vedo import load

# https://free3d.com/3d-model/091_aya-3dsmax-2020-189298.html
mesh = load("091_W_Aya_100K.obj").texture("tex/091_W_Aya_2K_01.jpg")
mesh.lighting('glossy') # change lighting (press k interactively)

mesh.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You so much for the help . That saved my day . Huge Huge thumbs up for your immediate response . That worked great . Can I get in touch with you I have few more queries . Would you wish to help me if you can . I need to know how to deform the mesh and wrap one over another using vtkplotter . Could you help me .

Comment: i'm happy that worked for you, an even faster way to get help is to open an issue in the github repo. There's a nr of examples about deforming meshes in https://github.com/marcomusy/vtkplotter-examples to see if any fits your needs.

Comment: Sure will check there . Thanks for your support :)

Comment: Now vtkplotter is changed to vedo, so the import will be "from vedo import load
". Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you can act like this:

```
import numpy as np
import trimesh
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("Lmobl/texture.png")
mesh = trimesh.load('Lmobl/raw_model.obj',process=False)
tex = trimesh.visual.TextureVisuals(image=im)
mesh.visual.texture = tex
mesh.show()
```

and here the result:
[image]

and for without texture, you'll find answer [here](https://github.com/pclausen/obj2png)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use f3d for that : 
https://gitlab.kitware.com/f3d/f3d/-/releases

```
f3d /path/to/3dmodel.obj
```